# Would you play this card game?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider the following game: at each round of game, $n^2$ cards, numbered from $1$ to $n^2$, are shuffled; you pick a card randomly. If you pick the card with number $1$ you win that round; each round costs one cent to play. Each time you win, you receive $\$100$. Would you play this game? Why or why not?

Comment: Sorry, you only win if you pick card $1$?  so you win with probability $\frac 1{n^2}$?

Comment: Assuming that I have understood the rules correctly...for a given $n$ compute the expected return, $E_n$.  Here you win $99.99$ if you draw the $1$ and you lose $.01$ if you draw something else.  I would argue that you should only play if your expectation is $>0$ but that's something of a subjective matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit: thanks to lulu and Jorge for pointing out my mistakes.

Probability of winning, $\frac{1}{n^2}$, gain $\$99.99$

Probability of losing, $1-\frac1{n^2}$, damage $\$0.01$

Expected gain is $$\frac{99.99}{n^2}-\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)0.01=\frac{100}{n^2}-0.01$$

when will the expected gain be positive?

$$\frac{100}{n^2}>0.01$$
$$n^2<\frac{100}{0.01}=10000$$

$$n < 100$$

Hence if I were to just maximize my expected gain, I would play it if $n < 100$. However, it depends on how much risk you are willing to take. what is your utility function?

Comment: aren't the calculations slightly off?

Comment: yikes... thanks